# Sigma HSM lens won't focus on Nikon D5300

Tags: lens, sigma, nikon-d5300

I tried the Sigma 70-200mm 1:2.8 Macro HSM EX DG APO on my Nikon D5300 and it won't autofocus even though the lens is supposed to have a built-in motor.

I've checked the camera settings to make sure they're set on automatic AF (tried different combinations) but the lens won't focus.

Additionally, there's no M/A switch on the lens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

[Sigma issued an advisory about compatibility with the D5300](http://www.sigma-photo.co.jp/english/new/new_topic.php?id=402) in late 2013. They have released firmware updates for lenses that can be upgraded via their [USB dock](http://www.sigma-global.com/en/lenses/cas/product/accessories/usb-dock/).

Unfortunately, the 70-200mm f/2.8 lens is not one of the compatible lenses listed for the USB dock. <s>It appears your lens may not be compatible with the Nikon D5300.</s>  Because you can't update the lens using the USB dock, you will have to contact Sigma to have the lens updated. From the advisory,

> You can contact your nearest authorized Sigma distributor for the firmware update. From the link below, you can see where to contact in our world network. http://www.sigma-photo.co.jp/english/network/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your nikon is version 1.03 or blow, after 1.04 the sigma HSM line does not communicate well with the nikon 5000 series.

i had the exact same issue, i downgraded from 1.10 to 1.03 and boom! the auto focus works again.